# Docusign Require Click on Link

Tags: docusignapi

I'm wondering if it is possible to require a hyperlink to be clicked in docusign eSignature before the signer can continue. I know you can create a hyperlink using these instructions https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/How-to-create-a-hyperlink-in-DocuSign?language=en_US&rsc_301 but want to know if there is a way to require it is clicked. Thanks

Tried https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/How-to-create-a-hyperlink-in-DocuSign?language=en_US&rsc_301  but dont see a way to make the link required to be clicked by all signers of an envelope

Answer (score 0):

If you [build an integration](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/build-integration/) and use [embedded signing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/embedding/), then you can certainly do that. It will be your application that has the additional link, that you show the user before you take them to the signing experience.
You cannot do this using [remote signing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/) where DocuSign sends the emails to the [recipients](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/recipients/), as the links in these emails takes them directly to sign the document.